# Rebuilding a C++ program with OpenCV on a VM

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, compilation

I need to switch from an ubuntu 20.04 to a Windows 7 workstation.

I'm writing a program for Raspberry PI that needs pthread, so I need a linux test environment.

I installed an ubuntu 20.04 VM and reinstalled all the libraries used in my program :

- OpenCV 4.2
- Libtorch
- NumCpp

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(POC_V4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Specifying we are using pthread for UNIX systems.
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

if(NOT Torch_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Pytorch Not Found!")
endif(NOT Torch_FOUND)

message(STATUS "Pytorch status :")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status :")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(POC_V4 <all_my_sources_and_headers>)
target_link_libraries(POC_V4 ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(POC_V4 pthread dl util)
```

On the real PC and on the VM, the cmake output is the same:

````sh
-- Pytorch status :
--     libraries: torch;torch_library;/usr/lib/libc10.so
-- OpenCV library status :
--     version: 4.2.0
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
--     include path: /usr/include/opencv4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: <path_where_i_build>```
````

On my real Ubuntu PC, the build works properly, but it fails during linkage on the VM :

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/src/communication.cpp.o: in function `Communication::showImage(cv::Mat, Box, std::string)':
communication.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/src/communication.cpp.o: in function `Communication::showImage(cv::Mat, std::string)':
communication.cpp:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/src/communication.cpp.o: in function `Communication::fps(cv::Mat, std::string)':
communication.cpp:(.text+0x655): undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/src/communication.cpp.o: in function `Communication::Communication()':
communication.cpp:(.text+0x816): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/src/imageGetter.cpp.o: in function `ImageGetter::ImageGetter()':
imageGetter.cpp:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/build.make:285: POC_V4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/all] Error 2
```

**TLDR :**

- Same OS
- Same library versions (OpenCV 4.2)
- Same CMakeLists.txt file

Linkage problem with OpenCV...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure the list of found OpenCV libraries (`libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn...`) is exactly the same? Also, have you seen the responses in this [thread](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13000) for a similar problem?

Comment: Yes, I copied and paste the two console outputs in two files, and switched from one to the other. They are even in the same order. The only difference between the two console outputs is the path where I build

Comment: I'll try what's on your link tomorrow, I don't have acceds to my VM right now. Thanks for the answer, I'll come back to you

Comment: @squareskittles  I've tried to add the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE`, no changes.
I also tried to rollback to the CXX_STANDARD to 11, but pytorch won't compile, it needs standard 14. The last thing I can try is to rebuild openCV, but I can't understand why I would have to do that if I didn't have to for the previous dev environment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, thanks to @squareskittles :
I needed to uninstall OpenCV, and rebuild it from source to the good version, with C++14 standard.

If you have linking problems related to OpenCV when building, uninstall OpenCV and build it yourself :

```sh
sudo apt remove libopencv-dev && sudo apt autoremove

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 4.2.0
cd ../opencv
git checkout 4.2.0
mkdir build
```

Open the `CMakeLists.txt` and add the following line at the beginning of the file :

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

Then build OpenCV :

```sh
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Downloads/opencv_contrib/modules/ ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Install potentially missing libraries for graphical output handling.

```sh
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Try re-building the project, that should work !

Thx again @squareskittles !

Comment: I was working on this for hours. Your solution was the only one to help, thanks for ending my day on a good note!

Comment: Glad I could help, thanks for the comment! 